# ¿Cómo quitar el color gradiente de fondo de un JButton de un Look and Feel y además se pueda modificarlo al pasar el mouse?

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas, quisiera modificar el `JButton` para que no me muestre colores degradados sino colores sólidos sin ningún efecto, estoy usando el `Look and Feel` `Aluminium` y me imagino que tengo que modificar la clase del `JButton` pero no sé como hacerlo para que ya no me aparezca el degradado sino el color simple. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu botón debes usar el método `setBackground` para definir el color y `setOpaque` configurado en `true`, ya que `setBackground` solo funciona cuando el botón es opaco. Si la instancia de tu botón se llamaría `jButton`, el código sería el siguiente:

```
jButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
jButton.setOpaque(true);
```

Sin embargo, dependiendo de tu `Look and Feel`, este podría ignorar el valor configurado en `setBackground`. Ver más información [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color))

---

**Otra opción:**

En caso de que el `Look and Feel` ignore el color y la opción anterior no funcione, podrías crear una clase que herede de `JButton` y que sobreescriba el método `paintComponent` para pintar manualmente el botón:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PlainJButton extends JButton {

    private Color color;

    public PlainJButton() {
        color = Color.RED;
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setFocusPainted(false);
    }

    public void changeColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        final Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        graphics2D.setPaint(this.color);
        graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics2D.dispose();
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

En vez de crear un JButton, se deberá crear un PlainJButton:

```
PlainJButton plainJButton = new PlainJButton();
```

---

Si se desea cambiar el color cuando se pasa el mouse sobre el botón, se puede llamar a `addMouseListener` y pasarle un `MouseAdapter` que sobreescriba los métodos `mouseEntered` y `mouseExited` para llamar a `changeColor` con los colores que se desee:

```
plainJButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        plainJButton.changeColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        plainJButton.changeColor(Color.RED);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ya lo hice de esa forma, pero el Look and Feel Aluminium, pone por defecto un gradiente, entonces al hacer el setBackground(Color.Black); me pone un negro degradado

Comment: De acuerdo, agregué ahora en mi respuesta una nueva forma de hacerlo, la cual si funciona utilizando el Look and Feel aluminium.

Comment: Muchas gracias! una pregunta más: y si quisiera que el color de fondo cambie al pasar el mouse, ¿como lo haría?

Comment: Hice cambios a la respuesta original y he agregado la explicación de para cambiar al pasar el mouse.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo! Me ha servido de mucho

Comment: Excelente, me alegro! Sería bueno que edites el texto de la pregunta original para explicar que también quieres que se cambie el color al pasar el mouse encima. De esta manera será más fácil encontrarla para otros usuarios que tengan la misma duda.

Comment: Gracias, lo haré! También estaba leyendo que es posible modificando el ButtonUI haciendo uno propio, pero la verdad no sé muy bien como modificarlo, de todos modos agradezco tu paciencia